# KickStart installation in RHEL6?

Tags: rhel

Is it reallly required to keep kickstart file ks.cfg inside RHEL6 directory to perform kickstart installation. Because if i do it the other way by keeping ks.cfg file outside RHEL directory the error reports as

UNABLE TO READ PACKAGE METADATA REPOSITORY.

and What is the difference Between NFS and KICKSTART installations ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to configure ur DVD as a Kickstart DVD make a folder called "ks" and place the ks.cfg inside it.

In NFS installation all ur packages are accessible through NFS share. Even u can keep ur kickstart file in a remote share like NFS or FTP, configure it that it remotely access the packages from a shared NFS or FTP drive.

Or u can go ahead with a PXE based installation  if your motherboard support it.